# Unable to submit JQuery datepicker value in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, datepicker

I added a datepicker (https://github.com/deepwell/meteor-bootstrap-datepicker) to my project, but am struggling to submit the chosen date to my Mongo document.

If I use the following code as-is, the datepicker works just fine, but the submit event does not work. The datepicker field is still cleared, however.

If I comment out the three Template.datepicker.rendered lines, the form submit event works just fine and inserts into the Mongo document. Ideas?

```
// item.html

{{#if editMode}}
{{> datepicker}}
{{/if}}

// datepicker.html

<template name="datepicker">
  <form class="form-inline mod-field item-due">  
    <div class="mod-field">
      <span>Due date: </span><input type="text" name="text" class="datepicker" />
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

// datepicker.js

Template.datepicker.rendered = function() {
  this.$('.datepicker').datepicker();
};

Template.datepicker.events({
  'submit .datepicker': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var itemDue = event.target.text.value;

    Items.update(this._id, {$set: {itemDue: itemDue}});

    event.target.text.value = "";

    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, either in the terminal or browser console?
Also in your event map you should target the form if you want to use submit, like this `'submit form': function()`

Comment: Nothing showing. Even if I start the submit event with a console.log I don't see anything on the console. The submit it pointing to the form with item-due.

Comment: Try a different event. add `<div class="click-me">Click</div>` then try rewrite your event `'click .click-me': function (event) { console.log('the event happened!') }` Because everything looks fine to me except choosing the wrong element for your submit event

Comment: In the click event you can access the text from your input element with simple selector `var itemDue = $('.datepicker').val()`

Comment: The click-me event worked just fine. Which makes things all the much weirder. I then amended the event to try the selector you mentioned, and still no luck:

`var itemDue = $('.datepicker').val();`

Comment: Did some more work - there's something with the datepicker not closing that is causing this to fail. The date never submits when the datepicker is still up (it does not hide when I choose a date). when I click away, generally the focus leaves the field. But every now and then, when the focus does not leave the field when I click away, then when I hit submit with the datepicker window gone, the function works. I simply added a button after the datepicker such that the click event submits the date. I still want to figure out how to do it without the button, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution ended up being pretty simple. When the window was still up, the date was not officially registering as the value. The key was adding the `autoclose: true,` command.

```
Template.datepicker.rendered = function() {
  this.$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
  });
};
```